# Why are the values in my random list are always the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-testing

This code is for a maximum pairwise product, I've been testing it but I have come across some issues.

```
import sys
import random
while True:
    a=int(random.randrange(1,1000000,101))
    keys =[]     # keys is empety list
    i=0

    while i < a :
        keys.append(int(random.randrange(1,10000,8)))
        i=i+1

    keys.sort()
    print(keys[-1], keys[-2])
    x=keys[-1]*keys[-2]
    print( "the max is ",x)
```

However, for some reason, the output of the code is always the same.

```
9993 9993
the max is  99860049
9993 9993
the max is  99860049
9993 9993
the max is  99860049
9993 9993
the max is  99860049
```

I don't understand why this is happening, an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Euh the `keys` are the same as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are sorting your list, so that the largest numbers are at the end. The list keys is going to contain hundreds of thousands of numbers, and as there are only 1249 possible keys `(9993 - 1) / 8 = 1249` you are incredibly likely to get two instances of the largest possible number, 9993. However, this isn't always the case, when I ran your code one time I got a different result:

```
9993 9993
the max is  99860049
9993 9993
the max is  99860049
9977 9969 #<-- Not 9993
the max is  99460713
9993 9993
the max is  99860049
```

This demonstrates how it is purely down to chance, I hope this helped!

Comment: now i have a little change in my code to make sure that error will disappear   i have replaced `random.radrange()`  with `random.randint()`

Comment: thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your `a`, is too big if you hard code to say 100 then you get the desire behavior

```
9945 9857
the max is  98027865
9905 9881
the max is  97871305
9969 9881
the max is  98503689
9977 9849
the max is  98263473
9977 9945
the max is  99221265
9713 9617
the max is  93409921
9993 9977
the max is  99700161
9929 9841
the max is  97711289
9881 9761
the max is  96448441
9953 9841
```

you choose your `a` as

```
>>> random.randrange(1,1000000,101)
18181
>>> random.randrange(1,1000000,101)
835069
>>> random.randrange(1,1000000,101)
729524
>>>
```

while your keys are selected from a pool of only

```
>>> len(range(1, 10000, 8))
1250
>>>
```

(more or less one)

with only 1250 different elements to choose from when you take way more than that (like 18181) more often than not you would get all the possibles numbers in that range (several times) and therefore you always get the same result, and with so many try you are almost guaranty to get the maximum number in that range (9993) several times and as sort that list that is why you get it as your result so many times.

This is know as the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

---

For what you do, consider using sample instead

```
for _ in range(5):
    a,b = random.sample(range(1,10000,8),2)
    print(a,b)
    print( "the max is ",a*b)
```

output

```
2881 689
the max is  1985009
2329 6473
the max is  15075617
5953 7769
the max is  46248857
9905 3201
the max is  31705905
6897 4713
the max is  32505561
```